# Bring element infront of other element without touching other elements

Tags: html, css

I have this structure:

```
<div class="destination full">
  <span class="sign">?</span>
  <span class="word" data-id="0.705074201440127">this</span>
  <span class="word" data-id="0.36336623481795605">is</span>
  <span class="word" data-id="0.8481199104419181">magical</span>
  <!-- <span class="word" data-id="0.84811991044191851">add or remove</span> -->
</div>
```

Note that we can add or remove `word` elements. The issue is to find a proper CSS solution to brig `sign` element in front of all other words (to create a question sentence right?) with touching `word` elements (I mean I still want the sentence to be meaningful)

NOTE: We can not touch the structure of the HTML .

Comment: _"to brig sign element in front of all other words (to create a question sentence right?)"_ - so _not_ in front, but you want to move it to the _back_ - yes?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.destination {
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 0.3ch;
}

.sign {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="destination full">
  <span class="sign">?</span>
  <span class="word" data-id="0.705074201440127">this</span>
  <span class="word" data-id="0.36336623481795605">is</span>
  <span class="word" data-id="0.8481199104419181">magical</span>
  <!-- <span class="word" data-id="0.84811991044191851">add or remove</span> -->
</div>
```